# Create Multiple Circle

Tags: vector, features, extents, circle, openlayers-2

I am trying to make many points in a map as a grid.
The code makes what I expect but the time to load is quite long so I suppose that there should be other ways to be more efficient drawing many circles.
The code used is the one below (the script).

```
<script>
    var map;
    function Initialize() {
        LoadMap(40.36, -3.66, 6);
    }

    //***************************************
    // MAP
    //***************************************

    function LoadMap(lat, lon, zoom) {
        //Define map options

            var fromProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");                                                    // transform from 3857?  //4326,900913
            var toProjection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");                                                    // to Spherical Mercator Projection
            var extent = new OpenLayers.Bounds(-7.5, 36.5, -2.5, 39.5).transform(fromProjection,toProjection);  // (W,S,E,N)
        var options = {projection: "EPSG:900913", units: 'km'};
        map = new OpenLayers.Map("mapDiv", options);

        //base map
            var ghyb = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google( "Google Hybrid", {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID, visibility: false} ); //numZoomLevels: 22

            //Switch control
            map.addLayers([ghyb]);
            map.addControls([new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar()]);

        //Build up all controls           
        var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat).transform(
                new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // transform from WGS 1984
                map.getProjectionObject() // to Spherical Mercator Projection
              );

        //Center the map    
        map.setCenter(lonLat);
        map.zoomTo(zoom);

        //add Rectangle
            var style = new OpenLayers.Style({
                fillOpacity: 0.0,
                fillColor: "#7ab800",
                strokeOpacity: 1,
                strokeColor: "#7ab800",
                strokeWidth: 3
            });

        boundingLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Bounding Layer",{styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap(style)});
            box = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(extent.toGeometry());
            boundingLayer.addFeatures(box);
        map.addLayer(boundingLayer);


        //Circles layer
            for (i = 36.5; i <= 39.5; i = i + 0.25) { 
                for (j = -7.5; j <= -2.5; j = j + 0.25) { 
                   lonLatLocation  = new OpenLayers.LonLat(j, i).transform( // LonLat(lon, lat)
                               new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),      // transform from WGS 1984
                               map.getProjectionObject()                            // to Spherical Mercator Projection
                             );
                   vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Circles Layer");
                   map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
                   createCircle(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(lonLatLocation.lon, lonLatLocation.lat));
                }
            }
    }

    //Add circles to circles layer
    function createCircle(center) {
        vectorLayer.removeAllFeatures();
        var sunpoly = OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon.createRegularPolygon
            (
                center,
                1000 / Math.cos(50 * (Math.PI / 180)),
                36,
                0
            );

        var suncircle = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(sunpoly, null, { fillOpacity: 1.0,
                                                                                                fillColor: "#FF0000",
                                                                                                strokeOpacity: 1,
                                                                                                strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                                                                                                strokeWidth: 3 });
        vectorLayer.addFeatures([suncircle]);
    }

</script>
```

Is there any other better way?

Comment: Please define "quite long". For me, it loads in about half a second. https://jsfiddle.net/GFarkas/w2ea55sp/

Comment: By lowering the redundancy (interchanging duplicated projection constructions and queries, and declaring the constant denominator outside the iteration), the code runs 20-30 ms faster, but I think that is the maximum. https://jsfiddle.net/GFarkas/Lgmnqmb4/

Comment: Gabor Farkas, "quite long" means for me too much. 21x13=273 circles I think that are not many circles and I expected to be another way to have a faster code. Thank you for your proposal anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To squeeze out every little bit of your code, you should get rid of the main bottleneck, plus lower the redundancy, like [here](https://jsfiddle.net/GFarkas/Lgmnqmb4/1/). The code can run under 200ms, which is very good compared to the original 500ms runtime.

The main bottleneck is in the `createCircle` function. If you don't need every point to be present in a separate layer, you should pull the layer construction out of the function, as it will create a new layer on every iteration.

There projection objects can also cause some redundancy. As they were declared and constructed in the beginning of the code, you should use them up. They can be used multiple times.

Also, giving the `center` property to the `map` object, instead of calling `setCenter` grants a few ms boost to the code.

Comment: that's a nice improvement. A very good solution. I didn't realized that I was doing a circle in different layers which makes a real bottleneck (ups!).